# Completely disable a handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I have just started using handsontable with JSON data and its working great but I need to disable all table input to certain users (read-only view).

Is there a way to completely disable a handsontable so none of the inputs respond and the remove row plugin doesn't function? I have tried http://dougestep.com/dme/jquery-disabler-widget-demos which doesn't seem to work and http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element which works but it essentially creates an iframe overlay over the controls and with the removerow plugin the position is off set incorrectly.

Comment: Have you tried the readOnly option ? 
https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Options
http://handsontable.com/demo/readonly.html

Comment: I have considered it but it will be messy to set read only at column level and then specifically disable the remove row plugin too. I was hoping there was a way at table level.

Comment: You can disable the whole table with the cascading options?
https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Options#how-does-cascading-configuration-work

And what's the remove row plugin?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To fully "disable" a Handsontable I have done the following:

```
hot.updateSettings({
    readOnly: true, // make table cells read-only
    contextMenu: false, // disable context menu to change things
    disableVisualSelection: true, // prevent user from visually selecting
    manualColumnResize: false, // prevent dragging to resize columns
    manualRowResize: false, // prevent dragging to resize rows
    comments: false // prevent editing of comments
});
```

Comment: @PatrikKarisch Thank you for editing my code to change some blatantly stupid places where I had erroneously copied `false` where I meant `true`...!  And without shouting at me!  Because the gist of what my code does is useful, even though I clearly did not look closely enough at what I pasted...

Comment: You're welcome! Your code was really helpful as it disables the table completely and look beautiful too. `readOnly: true` only would leave selection and so and it doesn't feel really disabled without all your other options :)

Comment: This deserves to go up!

I hope you don't mind, that I also changed your JS syntax ;)

Comment: The reason my syntax was not "neat", and that I had "erroneous glitches", is that in my code each attribute is done separately as wanted, and I had to gather the settings all together for here.  I am happy that your changes are correct and make it neater for standalone code.

Comment: if you are using handsontable with React, you can access the `hot` object with `<Handsontable ref=>{/*ref.hotInstance*/}/>`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the **updateSettings**

```
var hot = $("#exampleGrid").handsontable('getInstance');
hot.updateSettings({
        readOnly: true
    });
```

Check the following link:
http://jsfiddle.net/Hn3Zv/

Comment: This is a good start, but only disables cell editing.  Right-click still gives the "context menu", from which rows/columns can be inserted/removed, etc. Add `contextmenu: false` into `updateSettings()` to get rid of that too.

Comment: Sorry, to be exact it *must* be `contextMenu` (upper-case "M") and not `contextmenu` (same applies with `readOnly` versus `readonly`).  The all lower-case versions *seem* to work for "most" clicks, but do not always.